# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str' while trying to combine randint and

Tags: python, random, integer

I've seen several other versions of this question from 2014 and earlier, yet they all seem to be very far off what I need.

Code:

```py
while Play == True:
   computernum = str(random.randint(1,19))
   playernum = str(random.randint(1,10))
   print(str("Your first number is " + playernum + "."))
   playinput1 = input("Do you want to roll another number? <Y or N> ")
   if playinput1 == "Y":
       playernum0 = int(random.randint(1,10))
       playernum2 = int(playernum0 + playernum)
       break
```

Error response:

```
    *Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "program.py", line 41, in <module>
    playernum2 = int(playernum0 + playernum)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'*
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write this error line : `playernum2 = int(playernum0 + playernum)` in two methods:

If you want playernum2 as `int`:

```
playernum2 = playernum0 + int(playernum)
```

Or if you want playernum2 as `string`:

```
playernum2 = str(playernum0) + playernum
```